# Moq Verify that Update was never called for Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, rest, entity-framework-core, moq

The below doesn't fail for `MockBehavior.Loose` ( i.e. no Setup is needed )

```
void IContentDataStore.Update<T>(T entity)
{
    GetDbSet<T>().Update(entity);
}
```

```
[Test]
...
ContentStoreMock.Verify(repo => repo.Update(existingRequest), Times.Never );
```

For `MockBehavior.Strict` certain Setup is required.

What would any Setup be if this check makes sense at all ? There are already `expectedStatusCode: HttpStatusCode.BadRequest` and certain `Assert.That` for expected result string.

Comment: Could you please share with us the `GetDbSet` method and the whole test?

Answer (score 1):

In my case even for `MockBehavior.Strict` no Setup was needed, because Verify was purely for `Times.Never` ( i.e. No update happened )

Respective Rest Put method returns  BadRequest before doing anything else.

Test itself `Update_Should_ReturnBadRequest_When_NameIsInvalid()`

The below change made the test pass:

```
ContentStoreMock.Verify(repo => repo.Update(It.IsAny<MonitoringRequest>()), Times.Never);
```